# Why is the SCNNode becoming invisible when SCNNode.look is defined?

Tags: swift, arkit

I am playing around with Swift and ARKit. I can successfully display and update the mesh of a face using ARSCNFaceGeometry, ARFaceTrackingConfiguration etc. The head is not moving (it looks to user), but the face is updated with users face data.

However, if I want to make the face be able to react to user looking left and right, the face becomes invisible.
(If I move left and right, I sometimes see the edges of my nose/cheek but no more)

the code:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSessionDelegate {
    let session = ARSession()
    var maskNode: SCNNode?
    var sceneView = SCNView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(sceneView)

        self.sceneView.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
        self.sceneView.rendersContinuously = true

        if let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice(), let geo = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: device) {
            self.maskNode = SCNNode(geometry: geo)
            self.maskNode?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.fillMode = .lines


            self.maskNode?.look(at: SCNVector3(-0.01, -0.13, 0.932))
            self.maskNode?.position = SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)
            self.sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(self.maskNode!)
               }

        let config = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
        session.delegate = self
        session.run(config, options: [])

    }

    var currentFaceAnchor: ARFaceAnchor?


    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        guard let faceAnchor = anchors.first as? ARFaceAnchor else { return }
        self.currentFaceAnchor = faceAnchor
        let faceGeometry = self.maskNode?.geometry as! ARSCNFaceGeometry
        faceGeometry.update(from: faceAnchor.geometry)
        self.maskNode?.look(at: SCNVector3(faceAnchor.lookAtPoint))

    }
}
```

If the two self.maskNode?.look-lines are commented out, I clearly see the facial mesh. If not commented out, I hardly see anything.

The same if i do fillMode = .fill instead of .lines.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and what I am missing to see the correct lines/filled face moving around just like the user is moving his head around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out what was the case. For some reason, the z-coordinate in faceAnchor was opposite to that of maskNode?.look was expecting. So, changing the sign (*-1) of that particular coordinate did the job.